# Identical strings but not equal - what's going on?

Tags: ruby, string

This code:

```
io = StringIO.new "\xAF"
puts "\xAF".unpack('C')
puts (io.read 1).unpack('C')
puts 'Unequal' if io.read(1) != "\xAF"
```

Prints:

```
175
175
Unequal
```

Why are the two strings not equal when passed through `StringIO`? Clearly they both correspond to the value 175, but somehow they are not equal.

Comment: you're reading from `io` twice. The second read returns nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File objects (including `StringIO`) have a file pointer. Once the file is read/written, the file pointer advances.

```
io = StringIO.new "\xAF"
io.read(1)
# => "\xAF"
io.read(1) # File pointer advance. reached EOF. No more character.
# => nil
```

If you want to re-read the character, use `seek` method:

```
io.seek(0) # Move to offset 0
io.read(1)
# => "\xAF"
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly this is.. You beat me by 2 seconds

Comment: Sigh.. I _completely_ forgot about that! Of course. Thanks guys!